# realtek r8168 debian buster lost connexions on add-on card

Tags: debian-buster, realtek

We want to use 2 double port ethetnet card in lenovo M720e.
cards are dexlan ref FG-ENW02C-1-UC04  / pcie 1x dual giga ports.

we install debian 10.
we change grub so we have ethX and not enpXs0.
first card on pcie x16 port
second card on pcie x1 port  (no more pcie slot on motherboard)
after booting we have

eth0 = card 1 port 1

eth1 = card 1 port 2

eth2 = card 2 port 1

eth3 = card 2 port 2

eth4 = integrated card

all card are realteck
Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

we configure ip address on all eth.

we install r8168-dmks firmware-realtek on debian and use standard kernel. (4.19.xx)

now the problem
we use direct cable to a pc with linux . change change ip address on his ether card for each tests.

test en eth0 eth1 and eth4 ping / ssh / scp all OK
test on eth2 and eth3  ping ok / ssh not ok then ping not ok

so to be clear : we boot the lenovo , we plug a cable on eth3 ( or eth2) we ping the ip address on eth3 ( or eth2) , ping ok , we try ssh from linux pc to the lenovo no prompt for password nor to accept fingerprint , ctrl-C , try to ping  the ip address on eth3 ( or eth2) no ping anymore.

so we make tcpdump to see what happen :

linux pc : 10.98.127.45/24
lenovo pc : 10.98.127.10/24

on linux pc : ping 10.98.127.10
(the problem is here for more thant 5 minutes so need arp reply to work)

tcpdump on pc

```
12:24:21.302314 ARP, Request who-has 10.98.127.10 tell 10.98.127.45, length 28
12:24:22.333931 ARP, Request who-has 10.98.127.10 tell 10.98.127.45, length 28
12:24:23.357882 ARP, Request who-has 10.98.127.10 tell 10.98.127.45, length 28
```

tcpdump on lenovo :

```
12:24:21.301014 ARP, Request who-has 10.98.127.10 tell 10.98.127.45, length 46
12:24:21.301026 ARP, Reply 10.98.127.10 is-at 00:13:3b:4a:d7:7a, length 28
12:24:22.332649 ARP, Request who-has 10.98.127.10 tell 10.98.127.45, length 46
12:24:22.332660 ARP, Reply 10.98.127.10 is-at 00:13:3b:4a:d7:7a, length 28
12:24:23.356628 ARP, Request who-has 10.98.127.10 tell 10.98.127.45, length 46
12:24:23.356639 ARP, Reply 10.98.127.10 is-at 00:13:3b:4a:d7:7a, length 28
```

so we think that this is a problem on TX on eth3 in the lenovo pc

to get the ping working ( btu stop working if we try to ssh again )

on lenovo PC :

```
ip link set eth3 down ; ip link set eth3 up
```

we try thinks

- use debian backport to install r8168-dkms , firmware-realtek
- use debian backport to install 5.8 kernel
- unplug the working pcie card on the x16 slot
- replace the not working card with another one (we have 10+ of these card )
- in the lenovo bios deactivate integrated network card , vt-d , vt-x
- replace buster with stretch (same result)

each time we test and each time it's fail .

does anyone have ideas about that ?

I try to be complete but may be I forgot some tests/changes we made.
Sorry for my bad english

Nicolas

Comment: more informations

ping -s 200 10.989.127.10  also rise the problem , it's an mtu emission problem.

Comment: You should not disable predictable interface names; they should be enp*** instead of eth***. Otherwise, each NIC may have a different name each time hardware detection is done (i.e. at boot).